# Question about limit of Stochastic Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Given $\mu_t$ continuous stochastic process that satisfies $\int_0^t \mu_s^2\;ds<\infty$. Define $X_t\equiv \int_0^t \mu_s\;ds$. Let $|\cdot|$ denote floor function. Then where does $\sum_{n=1}^{|t/\Delta|}(X_{n\Delta}-X_{(n-1)\Delta})^2$ converge to in Mean Square as $\Delta\rightarrow 0$?

This is not  HW. My attempt has been to write $\sum_{n=1}^{|t/\Delta|}(X_{n\Delta}-X_{(n-1)\Delta})^2$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{|t/\Delta|} (\int_{(n-1)\Delta}^{n\Delta} \mu_s\;ds)^2$ and then I'm not sure how to proceed, despite knowing the definition of MS convergence.

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/727614/

Answer (score 0):

If $\mu$ is predictable and Lebesgue integrable, this converges to $0$. This is an Ito process with $\sigma =0$.

[Quadratic Variation of Ito process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#It.C5.8D_processes)